Plug-in (Euro-like) solar test set-up
I need to figure out what is required to plug a nominally 800-watt (8 x 100w) solar array into my household grid.  It is only for about a week while I see what difference adding panels w/o batteries will make.How do I make sure I don't oversupply my usage while I am running the test? Sending it back to the grid would flag PG&E before I am ready to decide between grid-tied (NEM 3.0 w.h. purchasing), off-grid, or grid-supplemented.  I still haven't decided between solar ecosystems.

A sub panel close to your main panel, but separated and only has some non essential circuits to use the solar power.  Getting a sub panel of the same make as your main, can move the breakers over plus the circuits.  Panels can be use as junction/splice boxes, so the circuit wires can be extended to the sub panel.

What do you mean by "Euro-like"? Euros spend in Europe without being like anything else.

@crip659 No, a sub-panel will not help with the situation: getting plug-in solar panels to not export to the grid (electric meters not set up for net metering will register exported power as imported). Cutting the grid feed to the sub-panel would prevent export but it would also prevent operation entirely: plug-in panels aren’t grid-forming.


How do I make sure I don't oversupply my usage while I am running the test?

Well let's do some math.  EPA says the average home uses 899 kWH/month or 29 kWH/day. That translates into an average 1.2 kWH/hour, or more simply said, 1200 watts on both poles or 5 amps at 240V.  That's the average. But you also have 5700 watt dryers, 4500 watt water heaters, 10,000 watt ranges - so for the average to work out at 1200 watts, then the "quiescent" (not much going on) load of a house must be very much under 1200 watts.
So no, you cannot inject 6.7 amps of power onto one 120V phase and rely on the house's quiescent loads to absorb all that. They won't.   You will need to run a space heater, bitcoin miner, or grow lights wide open on the same pole, as a "dummy load" to assure you are pulling from that phase at all times.
There's no other way to guarantee it otherwise. Houses just don't take enough power.

It is only for about a week while I see what difference adding panels w/o batteries will make.

That sounds like an XY problem, trying to get from measurement something the principles would tell you. Or, measuring something you don't actually need a solar panel to measure.
Consider an Emporia, Curb or Sense home energy monitor so you can fully understand your loads and put some hard numbers to that "quiescent draw" figure.
I don't know if an EV will ever enter your world, but it is extremely useful for absorbing solar energy.  The engineers at SAE designed the charging spec so the car responds dynamically to a "safe amps" signal sent by the house's charging equipment. This signal can be adjusted "on the fly" up and down to match solar output exactly (with a floor of 6 amps or 1440 watts@240V, 720W@120V).  And the Emporia EVSE does that, so that can inform a choice of home energy monitor.
Of course that only works when the car is present.  Other times you would need one kind of battery or another. I'm not loving "dumb tanked water heaters" for energy storage because heat pump water heaters are so ridiculously more efficient. It's cheaper to pay PG&E for the power to run a HPWH than it is to rack solar panels to heat a dumb water heater!  And in PG&E territory, 9 months of the year the HPWH is cooling a house that you want cooled.  Heat pump water heater as a dump makes sense, but it's not that big a load - only 1 kWH/day give or take.
Also note the cost of home battery systems are dropping fast, and this lends itself to DIY even more than solar systems do. Used EV battery prices are crashing in the marketplace. A 5 kWH Tesla module used to be $1200, now $300.
